# Best Practice testing angular on C/I like travis

Tags: angular, google-chrome, continuous-integration, travis-ci, e2e-testing

Hey what is the way to test an Angular app on an C/I like travis?

I createt a new Angular project with version 8.3.20 and the first thing what I tried, is how to use C/I. So I read the travis doc on how to use chrome -> https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/chrome

That did mostly the work, only the e2e test failing with the error message.
`E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78`

The chrome version on travis is `HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809` and I can not change the version.

I do **not** want to downgrade my tests to chrome version 76, this sound just not right for me.

Is there a Docker way to test an angular app with an explicit version of chrome? Also should I only test with chrome or would it make sense to also test it with firefox or some other browser?

My last question is how to badge the code coverage of my app. For python I used https://coveralls.io, is there also a typescript way?

My .travis.yml file:

```
dist: bionic

language: node_js

node_js:
  - "12"

os:
  - linux

services:
    - xvfb
    - chrome: stable

sudo: required

before_install:
    - # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
    - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &

install:
    - yarn

script:
    - yarn run lint
    - yarn run test -- --watch=false
    - yarn run e2e

cache: yarn
```

Thanks for your answers

**EDIT**

There is a guide on angular.io how to set up Travis & Circle CI

-> https://angular.io/guide/testing#set-up-continuous-integration

Answer (score 0):

Base on Angular travis ci example, you need one more addon, dpkg, to help travis ci server to install **deb** file of stable chrome which be indicated in **.travis.yml** .

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - dpkg
  chrome: stable
```